# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException when removing from collection

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, iterator, iteration

I'm having problem with my delete command of my array list while I'm iterating it.  How can I resolve the `ConcurrentModificationException`?

```
protected void deleteModeOfPayment(List<List<String>> AllModeOfPayment) {
    int ctr=0;
    List<String> thePayments =new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<List<String>> ia=allModeOfPayment.iterator();
    while(ia.hasNext()){
        thePayments=ia.next();
        String refOne= thePayments.get(1).toString().trim();
        if(refOne.equals(referenceIdentity)){
            log.d("ALVIN","ITEM TO BE DELETE FOUND");
            allModeOfPayment.remove(ctr);
        }
        else{
            ctr++;
            log.d("ALVIN","ITEM TO BE DELETE NOT FOUND");}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove doesn't need a parameter. and it should be ia.remove();

Comment: A) Please use proper variable names. Variables in Java are *not* uppercase B) it's doing exactly what the docs tell you it will do. Use the iterator's `remove()` method.

Comment: yes thats right the answer was ia.remove(); actually i was doing it by locating to my array list. and by your help guys ia.remove(); is the correct answer to my operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iterator to remove the element-

```
ia.remove();
```